# Nested resources, simple_form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to create an app where I have Events and each event would have many sales. When a new sale is created it automatically gets an event ID it belongs to. Could somebody please review this and tell me if I am doing something wrong, because I think the way am creating simple_form for the nested model(Sale) is a bit incorrect. Also I am not sure if it should be this way or I ve done something wrong, but when I am accessing nested children the url looks like this

```
.../events/4/sales/1 
.../events/3/sales/1 
.../events/5/sales/1
```

but I would expect it to be like this ?!

```
.../events/4/sales/1 
.../events/4/sales/2 
.../events/4/sales/3
```

Here is my controller and model for **Events**

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sales, dependent: :destroy
end
```

.

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @events = Event.all
  end

  def new
    @event = Event.new
  end

  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)

    if @event.save
      redirect_to @event
    else
      redirect_to events_path
    end
  end

  def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @sales = @event.sales
  end

  private

  def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:name, :comment, :event_disscount)
  end
end
```

.
Here is my controller and model for **Sales**

```
class Sale < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :sale_items

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sale_items, allow_destroy: true
end
```

.

```
class SalesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @sale = Sale.new(event_id: params[:event_id])
    @event = Event.find_by(id: params[:event_id])
  end

  def create

    @event =  Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @sale = @event.sales.create(params[:sale].permit(:receipt_email))

    if @sale.save
      redirect_to @event
    else
      redirect_to new
    end
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  resources :events do
    resources :sales
  end
  root 'events#index'

end
```

And this is how I use simple_form for sale(new)

```
<%= simple_form_for([@event, @sale])  do |f| %>
```

My main concern is the 'new' action in Sales controller, whats the best way to create a nested resource with the id of its parent, and then passing this object to the simple_form?!

Thank you in advance

Comment: How you are accessing the nested children? Update the question with the code

Comment: Few questions. What's the reason for ```@event.sales.build``` in ```new``` action of the controller? The code will work without it

Comment: Few questions. Why ```@sales = Sale.where(event_id: @event)``` in ```show``` action, when you can do just ```@event.sales``` ?

Comment: ```when I am accessing nested children the url looks like this``` - please show the code where you build URL for accessing nested children?

Comment: @IlyaKonyukhov  `@event.sales.build` - I am not really sure I was just trying something and forgot to delete it.  Oh yeah true it makes more sense to do it this way `@event.sales`. Ive updated my question. Apart from these 2 changes, is it correct the way I am creating new sale?

Comment: @IlyaKonyukhov , The only way I am building the url is just by doing this `resources :events do
    resources :sales
  end` Is there something else I should do?

Comment: My error was that I my link_to to sale (nested recourse) I wasnt passing the parent resource `<%= link_to event_sale_path(@event, sale) do %>` this is the right way to link to a nested resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too broad. Basically you're doing it all right, however, with some improvements on the code it will be easier to find possible problems.

> is it correct the way I am creating new sale?

Some improvements over your `SalesController`:

1. Create private method `sale_params` which will sanitize input params from your form. You did it for events already - why not to do it here too?
2. Since that controller works in the scope of event, `params[:event_id]` is set for every action. So create a `before_action` filter which will set your `@event` variable.
3. Method `create` saves the model to the database, so calling `save` after it makes no sense.
4. In case of failure on saving `@sale` to the db redirecting to `new` is not reasonable. In that case everything user typed in the form will be lost, validation error won't be shown and it will look like a glitch of your app. Render `new` template instead with the same `@sale`.

This is how I would rewrite your controller:

```
class SalesController < ApplicationController
  before_action: :set_event

  def new
    @sale = @event.sales.build
  end

  def create
    @sale = @event.sales.build(sale_params)

    if @sale.save
      redirect_to @event
    else
      render action: :new
    end
  end

  private

  def sale_params
    params.require(:sale).permit(:receipt_email, sale_items_attributes: [])
  end

  def set_event
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you I can see how much neater it is and reusable! And I would never think about the second point, so great help!